# Linking TypeCode and SqlDbType or DbType

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reflection

Is there a way i can link TypeCode enums and SqlDbType enums.
I'm planning on, when a specific variable in c sharp of any type identify its TypeCode i have a corresponding SqlDbType. Do i need to create table in my database to suffice my requirements. T.I.A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick to get the SqlDbType value for any given object. (It's not based on the TypeCode):

```
// create an SQL Parameter object
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("dummy", myObj);

// ask SQL code to compute its SqlDbType for us
Console.WriteLine(p.SqlDbType);
```

Comment: Letting SqlParameter to infer SqlDbType from value is a bad idea.
See: http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/29/why-you-should-always-specify-the-sqldbtype-for-an-ado.net.aspx

Comment: @user6694745 - Well, if your database is designed using ansi (varchar) and your sending unicode (nvarchar), of course it's not optimal (same for other types), but on the other side, it allows you to upgrade your database design w/o recompiling. Last time I used ansi to design a SQL database was more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Having to deal with a generic DbCommand which could be SqlCommand or MySqlDbCommand, i created this structure:

```cs
static readonly (Type type, DbType dbType, SqlDbType sqlDbType, MySqlDbType mySqlDbType)[] dbTypesRosetta = new[]
{
    (typeof(string), DbType.String, SqlDbType.VarChar, MySqlDbType.VarString),
    (typeof(string), DbType.String, SqlDbType.Text, MySqlDbType.LongText),
    (typeof(string), DbType.String, SqlDbType.Char, MySqlDbType.String),
    (typeof(char), DbType.StringFixedLength, SqlDbType.Char, MySqlDbType.String),
    (typeof(byte), DbType.Byte, SqlDbType.TinyInt, MySqlDbType.Byte),
    (typeof(short), DbType.Int16, SqlDbType.SmallInt, MySqlDbType.Int16),
    (typeof(int), DbType.Int32, SqlDbType.Int, MySqlDbType.Int32),
    (typeof(long), DbType.Int64, SqlDbType.BigInt, MySqlDbType.Int64),
    (typeof(byte[]), DbType.Binary, SqlDbType.Image, MySqlDbType.LongBlob), //Up to 8000 bytes for DbType
    (typeof(bool), DbType.Boolean, SqlDbType.Bit, MySqlDbType.Bit),
    (typeof(decimal), DbType.Currency, SqlDbType.Money, MySqlDbType.Decimal),
    (typeof(decimal), DbType.Decimal, SqlDbType.Decimal, MySqlDbType.Decimal),
    (typeof(float), DbType.Single, SqlDbType.Real, MySqlDbType.Float),
    (typeof(double), DbType.Double, SqlDbType.Float, MySqlDbType.Double),
    (typeof(TimeSpan), DbType.Time, SqlDbType.Time, MySqlDbType.Time),
    (typeof(DateTime), DbType.DateTime, SqlDbType.DateTime, MySqlDbType.DateTime),
    (typeof(DateTime), DbType.Date, SqlDbType.Date, MySqlDbType.Date),
    (typeof(DateTimeOffset), DbType.DateTimeOffset, SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset, MySqlDbType.DateTime),
    (typeof(byte[]), DbType.Binary, SqlDbType.Timestamp, MySqlDbType.Binary),
    (typeof(Guid), DbType.Guid, SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, MySqlDbType.Guid)
};
```

Scanning the tuple list linearly on the source "column", at the first occurrence i can find all the (mostly) corresponding equivalent types

That can be used in this way:

```cs
string s;
SqlDbType t = dbTypesRosetta.First(map => map.type == typeof(s)).sqlDbType;
//OR
MySqlDbType t = dbTypesRosetta.First(map => map.sqlDbType == SqlDbType.Int32).mySqlDbType;
//OR for creating a method like this:
public static DbCommand SetParamOutput<T>(this DbCommand cmd, string paramName, out DbParameter paramOutput)
    => SetParamOutput(cmd, paramName, dbTypesRosetta.First(map => map.type == typeof(T)).dbType, out paramOutput);
```

It is a type rosetta stone, actually ;))))

Answer (score 0):

The following method convert `TypeCode` to the corresponding `SqlDbType`.

If the `TypeCode` can't be mapped, error = true;

```
public static SqlDbType Typecode2SqlDbType(TypeCode typecode, out bool error)
{
    error=false;
    switch (typecode)
    {
        case TypeCode.Empty     :
             return SqlDbType.Variant   ;
        case TypeCode.Object    :
             return SqlDbType.Variant   ;
        case TypeCode.DBNull    :
             return SqlDbType.Variant   ;
        case TypeCode.Boolean   :
             return SqlDbType.Bit       ;
        case TypeCode.Char      :
             return SqlDbType.NChar     ;

        case TypeCode.Byte      :
             return SqlDbType.TinyInt   ;
        case TypeCode.Int16     :
             return SqlDbType.SmallInt  ;

        case TypeCode.Int32     :
             return SqlDbType.Int       ;

        case TypeCode.Int64     :
             return SqlDbType.BigInt    ;

        case TypeCode.Single    :
             return SqlDbType.Real      ;
        case TypeCode.Double    :
             return SqlDbType.Float     ;
        case TypeCode.Decimal   :
             return SqlDbType.Decimal   ;
        case TypeCode.DateTime  :
             return SqlDbType.DateTime  ;
        case TypeCode.String    :
             return SqlDbType.NVarChar  ;

        // can't map TypeCode.SByte  
        // can't map TypeCode.UInt16  
        // can't map TypeCode.UInt32  
        // can't map TypeCode.UInt64  
        default:
        {
            error =true;
            return SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        }
    }
}
```

}